# ldapsearch error "Invalid general option name" for every option

Tags: ldap

Whenever I try to use `ldapsearch` with a `-o` option I get the following error:

> Invalid general option name:

An example command I am trying to run (taken from [redhat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Administration_Guide/SASL.html)):

```
ldapsearch -p 389 -h server.example.com -o "mech=GSSAPI" 
    -o "authid=dn:uid=jsmith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" 
    -o realm=EXAMPLE.COM
```

But it doesn't matter what option I try, I still get this error. I also made sure `openldap` was up to date on this computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the documentation is wrong...looking at [the man page](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldapsearch&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&format=html) (version 2.4-Release), there're only *two possible general options*:

```
   -o opt[=optparam]

      Specify general options.

      General options:
        nettimeout=<timeout>  (in seconds, or "none" or "max")
        ldif-wrap=<width>     (in columns, or "no" for no wrapping)
```

That said, the man page has some related mentions, e.g.

```
   -E [!]ext[=extparam]
      Specify general extensions with -e and  search  extensions  with
      -E.  '!' indicates criticality.

      General extensions:
            [...]
    !authzid=<authzid>    ("dn:<dn>" or "u:<user>")
   [...]
   -O security-properties
      Specify SASL security properties.
   [...]
   -Y mech
      Specify the SASL mechanism to be  used  for  authentication.  If
      it's  not  specified, the program will choose the best mechanism
      the server knows.
```

so maybe one of these does the trick, just have a look at *your `ldapsearch`'s man page*.

There's a reference on common errors with [*Kerberos, GSSAPI and SASL Authentication using LDAP*](http://research.imb.uq.edu.au/~l.rathbone/ldap/gssapi.shtml) that might be helpful once the correct options are picked.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. I think your right, the doc is wrong or just outdated.

I did find all of the options I wanted by just doing a --help.

Just for completeness here is the command with all of the right options:

ldapsearch -p 389 -h server.example.com -X "authid=dn:uid=jsmith,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" -R realm=EXAMPLE.COM -Y GSSAPI